# How to set a custom font family as the default for an entire app in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

In SwiftUI you get all these handy little Font convenience accessors like `Font.caption`, `Font.title`, `Font.body`, etc..

e.g.

```
VStack {
 Text("Some Title").font(Font.title)
 Text("Some Caption Text").font(Font.caption)
}
```

They all specify different font styles for the default Helvetica font family. I'd like to use these very helpful convenience accessors without ever using Helvetica in my app. **Can I change the default font family?** Or do I constantly have to apply custom fonts like e.g.:

`Text("Custom Text").font(Font.custom("SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 14.0)`

Answer (score 22):

You can override the system font if you want.

```
    extension Font {
    
    /// Create a font with the large title text style.
    public static var largeTitle: Font {
        return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).pointSize)
    }

    /// Create a font with the title text style.
    public static var title: Font {
        return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1).pointSize)
    }

    /// Create a font with the headline text style.
    public static var headline: Font {
        return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline).pointSize)
    }

    /// Create a font with the subheadline text style.
    public static var subheadline: Font {
        return Font.custom("OpenSans-Light", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline).pointSize)
    }

    /// Create a font with the body text style.
    public static var body: Font {
           return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).pointSize)
       }

    /// Create a font with the callout text style.
    public static var callout: Font {
           return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout).pointSize)
       }

    /// Create a font with the footnote text style.
    public static var footnote: Font {
           return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote).pointSize)
       }

    /// Create a font with the caption text style.
    public static var caption: Font {
           return Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1).pointSize)
       }

    public static func system(size: CGFloat, weight: Font.Weight = .regular, design: Font.Design = .default) -> Font {
        var font = "OpenSans-Regular"
        switch weight {
        case .bold: font = "OpenSans-Bold"
        case .heavy: font = "OpenSans-ExtraBold"
        case .light: font = "OpenSans-Light"
        case .medium: font = "OpenSans-Regular"
        case .semibold: font = "OpenSans-SemiBold"
        case .thin: font = "OpenSans-Light"
        case .ultraLight: font = "OpenSans-Light"
        default: break
        }
        return Font.custom(font, size: size)
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes the SwiftUI live preview to crash in Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Works great with regular elements like `Text` but doesn't for `Section` headers or `navigationBarTitle`, any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This makes Preview crash in Xcode 13 with the following message: `replaced function 'system(size:weight:design:)' is not marked dynamic`

Comment: Still no fix for XCode 15.0.

Answer (score 11):

My current approach is to just recreate my own font factory:

```
struct MyFont {
  static let title = Font.custom("SourceSansPro-Bold", size: 24.0)
  static let body = Font.custom("SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 12.0)
}
```

and then use e.g. `MyFont.title` in place of `Font.title`

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach:

```
struct Fonts {

    static func oswaldRegular(size:CGFloat) -> Font{
        return Font.custom("Oswald-Regular", size: size)
    }

    static func oswaldLight(size:CGFloat) -> Font{
        return Font.custom("Oswald-Light", size: size)
    }

    static func oswaldBold(size:CGFloat) -> Font{
        return Font.custom("Oswald-Bold", size: size)
    }

}
```

Comment: May I have to add custom font into info.plist ?

Comment: Yes. Its mendatory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that combines some of these methods, specifically Justin's approach and Brady Murphy's Medium Article. The idea is to create a font manager that can be incorporated into a `Font` extension to override the default. I wish there were a compiler directive that could skip the Font extension for Previews. This will still break previews.

This func used once will grab the actual font names:

```
// put the following into the .onAppear of a top level view or App.init
func getCustomFontNames() {
    // get each of the font families
    for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        // print array of names
        print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
    }
}
```

Font manager that can create a default but also allows for multiple fonts by calling the font family struct directly.

```
typealias FMgr = FontManager
struct FontManager {
    
    // dynamic font sizes
    struct dynamicSize {
        public static var largeTitle    : CGFloat   = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).pointSize
        public static var title         : CGFloat   = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1).pointSize
        // repeat for all the dynamic sizes
    }
    
    // App Supplied Fonts
    struct Quicksand {
        static let familyRoot   = "Quicksand"
        
        // weights
        static let heavy        = bold
        static let bold         = "\(familyRoot)-Bold"
        static let semibold     = "\(familyRoot)-SemiBold"
        static let medium       = regular
        static let regular      = "\(familyRoot)-Regular"
        static let thin         = light
        static let light        = "\(familyRoot)-Light"
        static let ultralight   = light
        
        // dynamic sizes
        static let largeTitle   : Font = Font.custom(FMgr.Quicksand.bold, size: FMgr.dynamicSize.largeTitle)
        // repeat for other sizes
        
    }

    // structs for other fonts

}
```

```
extension Font {
    
    public static var largeTitle = FMgr.Quicksand.largeTitle
    // repeat for the rest of the dynamic sizes
}
```