# In SwiftUI I understand you can override Font but how to do it by %?

Tags: swift, swiftui, fonts

I'd like the .largeTitle modifier to be 25% bigger than it is. I still want to be in the world of SwiftUI fonts such that users can adjust on their own the overall accessibility for their preferred zone. However, .largTitle is still not big enough.

From [How to set a custom font family as the default for an entire app in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375481/how-to-set-a-custom-font-family-as-the-default-for-an-entire-app-in-swiftui)

I understand you can set actual font size like 48 or whatever, but I just want it to still adhere to the .largeTitle realm, I just want it 1/4-one half even bigger.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can specifically increase an already-existing size like `largeTitle`, but you could use ScaleMetric to affect a generally already-large point size by a certain amount: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scaledmetric

Comment: You could scale the `Text`